Controlling the new man page pop-up
Frequently while typing comands in Terminal, a yellow window pos up which tries to display a man page.
I haven't figured out what triggers it, but it's almost always empty and is trying to show man X where X is the most recent thing I typed.  Not once (so far) has it shown the command at the beginning of the line!
What is triggering this, and how can I stop it?  When I do want a man page (three times a week, not a dozen per day!), I have no trouble typing the command.

This might be new to you, but it isn’t new - it’s been around for ages - perhaps since OS X beta and enhanced with Lion.

May have been around for a while, but it was not happening when I got this laptop.  It has been irritating me for a few months but less than a year.

Second Bluetooth mouse under a book or in a bag is often the cause of cursor selects when someone isn’t consciously doing it. Or failing trackpad hardware or noise on logic board / connector for trackpad.

It's not another mouse.  Hope it's not a hardware issue!!

If you have a Touchbar Macbook Pro, there is a Man Page Touchbar button above the 2 and 3 buttons, so perhaps you are hitting that by mistake.

When did they add that?  It started happening long after I got this 2019 MBP.  And how do I stop it?  Edit the touchbar plist?

My fix to all of the touchbar mess was to use an external keyboard lol
